# Dynamically created GridLayout orientation not working when emulator in horizontal position

Tags: java, android

I am dynamically creating GridLayout with 9 buttons. However the horizontal orientation that I set for this GridLayout does not work when I change emulator to horizontal position. Here is my code -

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.GridLayout;
import android.widget.TableRow;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import static android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    GridLayout gl;
    Button[] buttons;
    int item;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        gl = new GridLayout(MainActivity.this);
        gl.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams
                (LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        gl.setOrientation(GridLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        gl.setColumnCount(3);
        gl.setRowCount(3);

        buttons = new Button[9];

        for(int i=0;i<9;i++)
        {
            buttons[i] = new Button(MainActivity.this);
            LayoutParams params = new TableRow.LayoutParams(WRAP_CONTENT, WRAP_CONTENT,1f);
            buttons[i].setLayoutParams(params);
            buttons[i].setHeight(WRAP_CONTENT);
            buttons[i].setWidth(WRAP_CONTENT);
            buttons[i].setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            buttons[i].setId(i+1);
            int s = buttons[i].getId();
            buttons[i].setText(Integer.toString(s));
            buttons[i].setTextSize(25);
            buttons[i].setWidth(352);
            buttons[i].setHeight(552);
            buttons[i].setPadding(50,50,50,50);
            gl.addView(buttons[i]);
        }

        setContentView(gl);

    }
}
```

Since I am not using activity_main.xml to create GridLayout I cannot set orientation in XML. Hence setting it in MainActivity.java at

`gl.setOrientation(GridLayout.HORIZONTAL);`

Also for each button dynamically created I cannot set layout_gravity to fill. Hence doing like this -

```
buttons[i].setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
```